# Is asta is the son of Licht and his human wife?

Tags: black-clover

we have seen licht can use the same sword as Asta and we have seen so far that Asta is the only one with the 5-star grimoire. Asta and Yuno both are orphans where Yuno seems to me like a son of royal because he is having a very huge amount of magic power like royalty. I think the pendulum in his neck will reveal his identity in the future. We already know the Licht was about to become the dad when the elf was attacked and everyone is dead. but what if Licht able to safe his son life? before his wife dead like he did with other elves soul. I think Asta is the son of Licht.

it seems like Asta is Half ELF and HALF human...  that is why we only able to see half part of him become demon.

Comment: I wanted to know this too and come to think of it that Tetia's element is wind and her child is not known if it is twin or not having a very large possibility that Yuno is also her child.

Comment: @Keith I believe Yuno is the son of Licht friend who was noble and equally powerful as Licht. Yuno is Asta cousin.

Comment: I highly doubt that Yuno is related to Asta in any way. Tbh, it does seem plausible that Yuno is royal blood. But then again, it won't be the first time we see someone who wasn't royal blood possessing massive reserves of mana (e.g the wizard king & Yami)

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin but Yuno act like Royalty, if he is not a belong to the royal blood still in his character it seems to me like like he is a royalty.